# Format string into smaller pieces and add whitespaces before second string

Tags: vb.net

I have specific request in my application, I have 2 strings and 30 characters per line free space.

First string will usualy be 20+ characters and if it exceeds 30 characters I need to insert line break (print new row) and add whitespaces so that second string goes to the right.

If I have these two strings:

```
Dim stringNumberOne as String = "string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1 "
Dim stringNumberTwo as String = "1,00"
```

This is how the end result should look like:

```
string1string1string1string1string
1string1string1string1string1strin
g1                            1,00
```

Because this should be written on POS printer I need to add `mstrStringToPrint &= ControlChars.NewLine` for each new line so the code should look like this:

```
mstrStringToPrint &= "string1string1string1string1string"
mstrStringToPrint &= ControlChars.NewLine
mstrStringToPrint &= "string1string1string1string1string"
mstrStringToPrint &= ControlChars.NewLine
mstrStringToPrint &= "g1" & emptySpaces & "1,00"
```

How would I achieve this in vb.net?

Comment: Tools to use are: string.Substring, string.PadLeft, string.Join

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Given the specs:

```
Dim maxLengh As Integer = 30
Dim line1 = "string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1"
Dim line2 = "1,00"
```

- One string to divide in **`MaxLength`** parts.
- Add a Line Feed + Carriage Return if the part length is `= MaxLength`.
- If the part length is `< MaxLength`, add a second line padding with white spaces to fill the string to `MaxLength`, if it can contain the second line.
- if the first string can be sliced exactly by `MaxLength` or the last slice cannot contain what's already there + the second line, add a new string, padding left by (`MaxLength - [second line].Length`)

---

```
Dim lines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

Dim pos As Integer = 0
While pos < line1.Length
    Dim part = If(pos + maxLength < line1.Length, maxLength, line1.Length - pos)
    lines.Add(line1.Substring(pos, part) & If(part = maxLength, ControlChars.NewLine, ""))
    pos += maxLength
End While
If (lines.Last().Length + line2.Length) < maxLength Then
    lines(lines.Count - 1) = lines.Last() & line2.PadLeft(maxLength - lines.Last().Length, " "c)
Else
    lines.Add(line2.PadLeft(maxLength - line2.Length, " "c))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stringNumberOne As String = "string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1string1 "
    Dim stringNumberTwo As String = "1,00"
    Dim NewString As String = String.Empty
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each c As Char In stringNumberOne
        If i = 30 Then
            NewString &= c & Environment.NewLine
            i = 0
        Else
            NewString &= c
            i += 1
        End If
    Next
    NewString = NewString & Environment.NewLine & stringNumberTwo.PadLeft(30, " ")
End Sub
```

I am not so sure what you want to do with that last line, this code will add a linebreak prior to padding 30 chars with space.